# How to put image inside QueryLoader by gayadesign

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys this Queryloader is working on my page but what  i want now is to put image inside the loader(ex. company logo). Please help

```
<script src="loader/queryloader2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    new QueryLoader2(document.querySelector("body"), {
        barColor: "#e7c665",
        backgroundColor: "#111",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 1,
        minimumTime: 300,
        fadeOutTime: 1000
    });
});
</script>
```

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin loads preloads all the images in the HTML. There is no provision to load only a subset of images. At least none as far as the documentation goes.

```
 It automatically fetches all your images and background images and preloads them before showing the webpage
```

-*from the [QueryLoader2 site](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/)*

Comment: So it is not possible to put image logo beside or above the percentage no.?

Comment: Oh...ok for that you can add your logo image, position it fixed and set a z-index higher than 666999. The overlay is positioned fixed with a z-index of 666999. For reference, you can check the [github repository](https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2/blob/master/src/Overlay/index.js#L57).

Comment: Can you give me a sample code where can i put the image src code. I have no idea. Thanks

Comment: You can add the logo image to the HTML as you would normally add it and apply the styles I mentioned above to it. No need to taker with the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add some CSS code...

If you want to add custom text:

`#qLoverlay::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'your custom text here';
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:40%;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
}`

If you want to add an image:

`#qLoverlay::before {
    position:absolute;
    content:url(exampleimage.png);
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:30%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following `CSS` rule:

```
#qLoverlay {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat center 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the css this way:

```
#qLoverlay{
position: relative;
}
```

Only change the top for adjust the image.

```
#qLoverlay::before {
position:absolute;
content:url('images/logoedit1.png');
text-align: center;
top: 25%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following where it creates the loading text, bar, and percentage

```
// CODE TO INSERT
            this.loaderLogo = $("<div id='loader-logo'></div>").css({
                    background: 'url("http://chrisrocco.net/elegantearth/res/images/logo.png") no-repeat',
                    backgroundSize: '100%',
                    height: "400px",
                    width: "900px",
                    margin: "25px auto",
                    fontSize: "60px",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    color: this.parent.options.barColor
            }).appendTo(this.container);
```

It belongs here, on line ~31 of queryloader2.js

```
    if (this.parent.options.percentage == true) {
            this.percentageContainer = $("<span id='qLpercentage'></span>").text("0%").css({
                    height: "80px",
                    width: "115px",
                    position: "absolute",
                    fontSize: "60px",
                    fontFamily: this.parent.options.fontFamily,
                    top: "75%",
                    left: "50%",
                    marginTop: "-" + (59 + this.parent.options.barHeight) + "px",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    marginLeft: "12px",
                    marginTop: "-120px",
                    color: this.parent.options.barColor
            }).appendTo(this.container);

            this.nameElem = $("<span id='elem-title'></span>").text("Loading ").css({
                    height: "80px",
                    width: "258px",
                    position: "absolute",
                    fontSize: "60px",
                    fontFamily: this.parent.options.fontFamily,
                    top: "75%",
                    left: "50%",
                    marginTop: "-" + (59 + this.parent.options.barHeight) + "px",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    marginLeft: "-270px",
                    marginTop: "-120px",
                    color: this.parent.options.barColor
            }).appendTo(this.container);

            // LINE 31
            // INSERT HERE
    }
```

You will, of course, have to tweak the css to your project

[*Picture of Result*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3LxQ.png)